# Write WithState in a Child Component in Recompose

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recompose

**Question №1**

Is it right to write WithState in a Child Component in Recompose? *Yes*? How can I transfer a state from a Child Component to a Parent Component?

**Question №2**

Is it right to write WithState and withHandlers in the Parent Component?

Comment: Yes ( lifting state up is common and [React documentation has a section dedicated to this subject](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)) and yes (any component can be decorated  withState and withHandlers but this depends on the context that they're used in).

Comment: @OluwafemiSule, Hmm, Lifting State Up. I did not know. Thank you. I will read.